# dispatch.fcgi for Rails 4 FCGI::Stream::Error in Dreamhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip, dreamhost, fastcgi

I've been using Rails 4(installed in user space) with Ruby 2.0 and FastCGI to run a Rails application that uploads a ZIP file which contains several images. Uses the Gem Paperclip to manage the uploads and generates thumbnails and insert a watermark.

The zip file uploads just fine and it process the file unziping the images and creating new Item model to insert into database, but it hangs at certain point and drops the error:

```
    %%%%%%%%%%%About to process sites/thisite/releases/20131125055016/tmp/_RH75239.jpg
Command :: file -b --mime 'sites/thisite/releases/20131125055016/tmp/_RH75239.jpg'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/_RH7523920131124-16069-ctt1e6.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/tmp/_RH7523920131124-16069-ctt1e6.jpg' '-resize' 'x150' '-crop' '150x150+37+0' '+repage' '/tmp/_RH7523920131124-16
069-ctt1e620131124-16069-1ggirgg'
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 119696ms

SystemExit (exit):
  app/controllers/items_controller.rb:95:in `block in createzip'
  app/controllers/items_controller.rb:76:in `createzip'


sites/thisite/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/fastcgi.rb:87:in `flush': unknown erro
r (syscall error) (FCGI::Stream::Error)
        from sites/thisite/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/fastcgi.rb:87:in `send_he
aders'
        from sites/thisite/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/fastcgi.rb:68:in `serve'
        from sites/thisite/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/fastcgi.rb:28:in `block i
n run'
        from sites/thisite/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/fastcgi.rb:27:in `each'
        from sites/thisite/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/fastcgi.rb:27:in `run'
        from dispatch.fcgi:32:in `<main>'
```

And the block of code looks like this

```
Zip::ZipInputStream::open(params[:file].tempfile) do |zip|
  while(entry = zip.get_next_entry)
    next if entry.name_is_directory?

    fnz = File.join( "#{Rails.root}/tmp", File.basename(entry.name) )
    fd = File.open(fnz, 'wb+')
    fd.write zip.read

    item = Item.new(
      :title => params[:title],
      :summary => params[:summary],
      :stags => params[:stags],
      :active => true,
      :season => params[:season],
      :game => params[:game],
      :match => params[:match]
    )

    puts "%%%%%%%%%%%About to process #{fnz}"
    item.file = fd

    if item.valid?
      if item.save
        @saved += 1
        @user.items << item
        @folder.items << item unless @folder.nil?
      else
        @errors << entry.name
      end
    end
    fd.close
  end
end
```

And the dispatch.fcgi file is this one:

```
#!/home/user/ruby/bin/ruby

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'production'
ENV['HOME'] ||= `echo ~`.strip
ENV['GEM_HOME'] = File.expand_path('~/.gems')
ENV['GEM_PATH'] = File.expand_path('~/.gems')

require 'fcgi'
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../config/environment.rb')

flog = File.open('fastcgi.log', 'a+')
STDOUT.reopen flog
STDERR.reopen flog
STDOUT.sync = true
STDERR.sync = true

class Rack::PathInfoRewriter
 def initialize(app)
  @app = app
 end

 def call(env)
  env.delete('SCRIPT_NAME')
  parts = env['REQUEST_URI'].split('?')
  env['PATH_INFO'] = parts[0]
  env['QUERY_STRING'] = parts[1].to_s
  @app.call(env)
 end

end

Rack::Handler::FastCGI.run Rack::PathInfoRewriter.new(Sampleapp::Application)
```

Thanks in advance.